# Calculating Duration from Factor Families

Tags: r

This is tricky and I haven't any idea how to do it.

I have several thousand observations:

- Each observation has a single date associated with it.
- Each observation also has a factor associated with it.
- Each family of factors has 1 - 10 members.

I need to add a duration to each observation, where, the duration is the difference between that observation, and the next chronological observation in that factor family. If there is only one observation in a factor family, or if the observation is the final in a set, I need to add a dummy variable that captures that fact and make its duration equal to a specific date.

This is a simplification of the form the data is in:

```
observation <- seq(1:50)
factor <- c(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )], letters[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )], letters[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )], letters[seq( from = 1, to = 3 )], letters[seq( from = 1, to = 3 )], letters[seq( from = 1, to = 4 )], letters[seq( from = 1, to = 9 )], letters[seq( from = 1, to = 1 )], letters[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )], letters[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )])
date <- seq(from = as.Date("1975/01/01"), to = as.Date("2015/01/01"), length.out = 50)
data <- data.frame(observation, factor, date)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want the result to be for the last date in a sequence, so see if the code below meets your needs. I've set the `last.date` column to be equal to the last date in a given factor's sequence or `NA` otherwise, but you can set these to whatever values you wish.

```
library(tidyverse)

data = data %>% group_by(factor) %>%
  mutate(duration = c(diff(date), NA_real_),
         last.date = if_else(date==max(date), max(date), as.Date(NA))) %>%
  arrange(factor, date)
```

> ```
>    observation factor       date       duration  last.date
> 1            1      a 1975-01-01 2981.6327 days       <NA>
> 2           11      a 1983-03-01 1490.8163 days       <NA>
> 3           16      a 1987-03-31 1490.8163 days       <NA>
> 4           21      a 1991-04-30  894.4898 days       <NA>
> 5           24      a 1993-10-10  894.4898 days       <NA>
> 6           27      a 1996-03-23 1192.6531 days       <NA>
> 7           31      a 1999-06-28 2683.4694 days       <NA>
> 8           40      a 2006-11-02  298.1633 days       <NA>
> 9           41      a 2007-08-27 1490.8163 days       <NA>
> 10          46      a 2011-09-26        NA days 2011-09-26
> 11           2      b 1975-10-26 2981.6327 days       <NA>
> ...
> 46           8      h 1980-09-18 8944.8980 days       <NA>
> 47          38      h 2005-03-16        NA days 2005-03-16
> 48           9      i 1981-07-13 8944.8980 days       <NA>
> 49          39      i 2006-01-08        NA days 2006-01-08
> 50          10      j 1982-05-07        NA days 1982-05-07
> ```

Comment: Thanks that might be nearly it! However, I'm getting an error when I attempt to run that code it, "Error: incorrect size (50) expecting : 1388. 

50 is the size of the sample data, and 1388 is the size of my final filtered dataset.. but, I don't see any lengths hard wired into your solution so I need to troubleshoot that to figure out. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the error. It's midnight and I'm a fool. You however are amazing, that worked perfectly. Thank you!!!!